# How do I add ads to my android-libGDX project?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, libgdx, ads

So I made my android-libGDX project and have my app finished and everything, but now I wanna add some ads. (because you know it costs $25 to make an account and I'm just a poor student).

I know how to add google Play services but I can't get any further. I have a AdMob account but I don't know how to display the add in the app.

Also, I have found some github pages where they explain, but I can't figure out still how they do it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here's the updated guide](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Google-Mobile-Ads-in-Libgdx-(replaces-deprecated-AdMob)) on setting up both admob banner and interstitial ads in a libgdx game using the google play services.

You can modify your code as provided in the docs as follows:

```
@Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    AndroidApplicationConfiguration cfg = new AndroidApplicationConfiguration();
    cfg.useGL20 = false;
    cfg.useAccelerometer = false;
    cfg.useCompass = false;

    // Do the stuff that initialize() would do for you
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN);

    RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout(this);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    layout.setLayoutParams(params);

    AdView admobView = createAdView();
    layout.addView(admobView);
    View gameView = createGameView(cfg);
    layout.addView(gameView);

    setContentView(layout);
    startAdvertising(admobView);
  }

  private AdView createAdView() {
    adView = new AdView(this);
    adView.setAdSize(AdSize.SMART_BANNER);
    adView.setAdUnitId(AD_UNIT_ID);
    adView.setId(12345); // this is an arbitrary id, allows for relative positioning in createGameView()
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
    adView.setLayoutParams(params);
    adView.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
    return adView;
  }

 private View createGameView(AndroidApplicationConfiguration cfg) {
    gameView = initializeForView(new AdTutorial(), cfg);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, adView.getId());
    gameView.setLayoutParams(params);
    return gameView;
  }

  private void startAdvertising(AdView adView) {
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    adView.loadAd(adRequest);
  }

  @Override
  public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (adView != null) adView.resume();
  }

  @Override
  public void onPause() {
    if (adView != null) adView.pause();
    super.onPause();
  }

  @Override
  public void onDestroy() {
    if (adView != null) adView.destroy();
    super.onDestroy();
  }
```